# Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop on brand new computer, trying to recover old encrypted data

Tags: partitioning, usb, encryption, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu onto a USB stick and encrypted all my data, however my laptop stopped working and I had to purchase a new one and my USB stick no longer boots into Linux.

So I have a brand new Ubuntu installation and I am trying to recover my data from my old home directory, when I plug the USB in it recognizes it and asked for the password etc but when I go to the old Home directory it just has a file called `Access-Your-private-data.desktop` and running that file does nothing.

No idea how to access my old files and hoping someone might be able to help?

Comment: How are you trying to run the `Access-Your-private-data.desktop`? what happens exactly when you try to run it (any error messages)? How are you accessing the old home directory, and how is it mounted (perhaps it is mounted "noexec")?